# Custom parameters in Pentaho dashboards

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-ctools

Custom parameters in a CDE/CTools dashboard are great for defaulting initial values of parameters, e.g. setting a date parameter to today.  i.e. the parameter looks like:

function() {
// some code
return val
}

However there is an issue with them. The first time you access a "custom parameter" in code, it is a function not a string. So you have to use:

paramName()

To get its value.

Once the end user selects a value then you have to use

paramName

This is really awkward in complicated dashboards with lots of prompts. Is there a better way this can be done? (Perhaps there is something in javascript I'm missing to help here?)

Comment: I don't use the dashboards, but what happens if you use paranName() after the value is selected?

Comment: you get a javascript error because you're trying to make a function call on something that is actually a string

Comment: you don't need to wrap it in a function. Whatever Javascript you put there will be evaluated and its return value will be used as parameter's value. E.g.: `['january', 'february', ..., 'december'][(new Date()).getMonth()]` will return the current month's name.

Answer (score 2):

OK, there is a solution, but I dont like it!

First; Move all the init code into named procedures e.g.

function monthInit() {
return "june";
}

Then in the custom parameter for month, just say:

monthInit();

That way the custom parameter is always a string, and never starts off as a function.

Not ideal though because then all your init code is in a separate bit of js.

Comment: thanks. Good tip. The "separate bit of js" is a script resource added to the layout section.